# dividing jw controlbar into two parts

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Is there any way to divide jwplayer 6 control bar into two parts.For example in first row there will be a time slide and in second row there will be control icons like play, Volume, Hd etc.
Something like youtube and tune.pk player.
Any idea?

Comment: I'm afraid our skinning model does not allow for two rows of buttons.